# parsing string using token and assigning to variables

Tags: c++, parsing

here is my loop

```
while(getline(iss,token,','))
     cout<<token<<endl;
```

the string in question is:

> john doe,freshman,email@email.com

running the while leave outputs:

```
john doe
freshman
email@email.com
```

My goal is to assign each piece of the parsed string to a variable.
example:

```
name = token;
cout<<"name: "<<name<<endl:
```

would produce

```
name: John doe
```

Then i would repeat for the other 2 pieces. Problem is I can't figure out to assign token to name, year, and email without it overwriting with each pass through the loop.

```
 90   string comma;
 91   string line;
 92   string token;
 93   ifstream myfile("student.dat");
 94   string name,email="";
 95   string status="";
 96   int id,i;
 97   if (myfile.is_open()){
 98     while ( getline (myfile,line) ) {
 99         //parse line
100         string myText(line);
101         cout<<line<<endl;
102         istringstream iss(myText);
103         if (!(iss>>id)) id=0;
104         i = 0;
105         while(getline(iss,token,','))
106         {
107             cout<<token<<endl;
108            
109            
110                 
111                
112            
113
114            
115         }
116         Student newStudent(id,line,"","");
117         Student::studentList.insert(std::pair<int,Student>(id,newStudent));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
std::string name, year, email;

if (std::getline(iss, name, ',') &&
    std::getline(iss, year, ',') &&
    std::getline(iss, email))
{
     newStudent = Student(id, name, year, email);
}
```

Extract parts of the string into individual variables respectively, then send them over to the constructor.

Comment: That doesn't see to work because it first says newStudent there is no output when I go to print out the contents of the map.

Comment: The only thing being printed is the id number. It doesn't look like anything is being stored in name, year, email.

Comment: It turns out all you need to do is `ignore()` before performing the first `getline()` call.